# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphDatabaseService'

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to run a sample neo4j python application and I'm getting this error message.

graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService(url)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphDatabaseService'

I did dir(neo4j) in console and found no attribute named "GraphDatabaseService" for neo4j.

Is there any other alternative for this?

This is the code I'm trying to run: https://gist.github.com/JnBrymn/6f84d42dc6ac5e251047

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code? :-)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/JnBrymn/6f84d42dc6ac5e251047

Comment: I suspect this was introduced with the release of py2neo 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have py2neo 2.0 rather than 1.6.x? The syntax has changed between versions.  Now you can do:

```
from py2neo import Graph
db_graph = Graph()
```

to connect to the default local database.  You can initialize a Graph object with any url.